# RxJava2 Flowable zip async method invoke

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2

A simple example:

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class RxTest {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RxTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException     {
        log.debug("start");
        RxTest rx = new RxTest();
        Flowable.zip(rx.m1(), rx.m2(), rx::result).subscribe( (r) -> log.debug(r));
    }

    private Publisher<String> m1() throws InterruptedException {
        log.debug("m2");
        String result = new TestRxObj().getObj(4000L, "Hello");
        return Flowable.just(result);
    }

    private Publisher<Long> m2() throws InterruptedException {
        log.debug("m1");
        Long result = new TestRxObj().getObj(100L, 777L);
        return Flowable.just(result);
    }

    private String result(String t1, Long t2) {
        log.debug("result");
        return t1 + "-" + t2;
    }

}

public class TestRxObj {

    public <T> T getObj(Long time, T t) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(time);
        return t;
    }

}
```

So the problem is, that I want to call methods m1() and m2() asynchronously

Right now i have this output:

```
2018-03-09 22:34:20 [main] DEBUG RxTest: 18 - start
2018-03-09 22:34:20 [main] DEBUG RxTest: 24 - m2
2018-03-09 22:34:24 [main] DEBUG RxTest: 30 - m1
2018-03-09 22:34:24 [main] DEBUG RxTest: 36 - result
2018-03-09 22:34:24 [main] DEBUG RxTest: 20 - Hello-777
```

On git, they have some example, how to run in new thread:

```
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(1000); //  imitate expensive computation
    return "Done";
})
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
  .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);

Thread.sleep(2000); // <--- wait for the flow to finish
```

But problem with this example, I don't know how to join to(Main/current) threat, to not write `Thread.sleep(2000);`. I'm running this not on Android, just simple java project, so I cannot `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, if I correct understand what this doing

My main goal, run 1..N(at least 2 :) ) methods asynchronously with RxJava2, 
if it can be done without `zip`, I ok with it, any approach with RxJava without `Thread.sleep(...)` :)

Comment: I hope you realize that `m1()` is invoked and executes before RxJava even gets involved. The only way to return to the Java main thread is to block the subscription or use a blocking scheduler. The former is easier with `blockingSubscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException     {
    log.debug("start");
    RxTest rx = new RxTest();
    Flowable.zip(
        Observable.defer(() -> rx.m1()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        Observable.defer(() -> rx.m2()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        rx::result)
    .subscribe( (r) -> log.debug(r));
}
```

For testing purposes, sometimes having the `Schedulers.io()` as a parameter or field is usefule, so you can replace it with a `TestScheduler`.